# How to get the next 10 dates from today (local)

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get the next get the next 10 dates starting with the current date from the device in Swift using this code. NSDate() is giving me GMT time not device time. I tried use an NSDateFormatter(), but that only gave me strings.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
for i in 0...10

    {
        let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: i, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        print(newDate)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have Update your code

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
for i in 0...10            
{
    let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: i, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    print(newDate)

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss a" // Customize format base on requirement
    print(formatter.stringFromDate(newDate!))       
}
```

I am getting `06:06:2016 10:04:06 AM`

Answer (score 1):

I improved @kb920's answer:

```
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss a" // Customize format base on requirement
    for i in 0...10
    {
        let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: i, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
        print(newDate)
        print(formatter.stringFromDate(newDate!))       
    }
```

And I recommend [DateTools](https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools)